# how to clear this syntax error in angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

i got error on this line `value: v2.this.listvalue`

```
this.listvalue='something';
list.forEach((v: any) => {

v.data.forEach((v2: any) => {


this.searchlist.push({
  header: v.header,
  value: v2.this.listvalue

});
```

i want to  call the v2 attribute which is in the listvalue variable how can i solve out this error >This code give the error Cannot read property 'listvalue' of undefined in the console log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
value: v2[this.listvalue]
```